# Azure Javascript - Wait for Function Completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, asynchronous, backend

I'm using Azure Mobile Services and am running a javascript backend. However, since the backend is in node.js, everything is executed asynchronously and I don't know how to halt the execution of a function.

I'm trying to delete a club if there hasn't been a comment in it within the past 24 hours, and here's my code:

```
var clubs = tables.getTable('Club');
clubs.read(
    {
        success: function(club){
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            for(var i=0;i<club.length;i++){
                var deleteClub = true;
                comments.where({ClubId: club[i].id}).read(
                    {
                        success:function(comment){
                            var timeDiff = (now-comment[i].Time.getTime())/(1000*60*60);
                            console.log("Comment in table: "+timeDiff);
                            if(timeDiff<24){
                                deleteClub=false;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                );
                if(deleteClub){
                    console.log("deleting club: "+club[i].Title);
                    //clubs.del(club[i]);
                }else{
                    console.log("saving club: "+club[i].Title);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The if statement executes before the delete club variable is updated, so it's always true, but I need the if statement's execution to be delayed until after all of the comments have been looped through.

Comment: What can't you put your `deleteClub` inside `success` callback ?

Comment: The success callback occurs for each comment that is retrieved, I need to check through all of the comments before calling the delete function.

Comment: I'm confused: What is `club` that it has a `length` and you index into it? How can you use the index you were using with `club` and use it to index into `comment`? The async problem is easily solved, but I'm not getting the code as a whole...

Comment: If you could tell me how to solve the async problem I would greatly appreciate it - a club is like a folder and comments are text entries that exist in that folder. However, clubs and comments have their own tables since there is a one to many ratio between them, and this relationship is managed using their ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the callback you get is asynchronous, you can't use any information you're getting in that callback in synchronous code after the `where` call.

Since we want to handle things on a club-by-club basis, first we'll move the handling of clubs into its own function. This avoids the problem that by the time we get our callback from `read`, `i` will have been incremented.

Your code seems to assume `success` is called repeatedly, once for each comment. I don't think that's likely to be the case, more likely it's called **once**, with a list/array of the matching comments.

If so, then splitting off club handling to its own function and then looping the found comments should do it:

```
var clubs = tables.getTable('Club');
clubs.read(
    {
        success: function(allClubs){ // <== Note plural
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            for (var i = 0; i < allClubs.length; i++) {
                handler(now, allClubs[i]); // <== Move handling off to a handler
            }
        }
    }
);
function handler(now, club) {   // <== Unlike `i` above, `club` won't change because it's
                                // a function argument that we never assign to
    comments.where({ClubId: club.id}).read(
        {
            success: function(comments){ // <== Note the plural
                var deleteClub = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; ++i) {
                    var timeDiff = (now-comments[index].Time.getTime())/(1000*60*60);
                    console.log("Comment in table: "+timeDiff);
                    if(timeDiff<24){
                        deleteClub=false;
                    }
                }
                if (deleteClub){
                    console.log("deleting club: "+club.Title);
                    //clubs.del(club);
                }else{
                    console.log("saving club: "+club.Title);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: If i was just doing a read query this would work, but I don't know the number of callbacks that will occur since I'm using a filter where ClubId must be equal to club[i].id.

Comment: @Oblivionkey3: There must be an overall "done now" callback offered by the API.

Comment: I wish, unfortunately the api for azure's javascript backend is minimal, and I've tried calling read(..,).done(func(){}); , but that throws an error. Here's a link to the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554226.aspx

Comment: @Oblivionkey3: Are you sure that the `success` callback isn't called just once, with a list/array of **all** matching comments? Your code suggests it's called per comment, but I suspect it isn't.

Comment: @Oblivionkey3: Yeah, looking at the documentation, I'm pretty sure `success` is called **once** with the matching records. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hey thanks so much, you're right - I don't know how I missed that.